# how to load xib view(UIViewController) from xib(UITableViewCell)

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, xib, navigationcontroller, awakefromnib

Here is what I already have;

- I have loaded a Custom cell from XIB file (UITableViewCell)
- This custom cell contains Button A and B
- Created a IBAction to handle Button A
- loaded above XIB file in MyTableView class (UIViewController)

Now I want to load another view(Most probably a XIB file) on Button A clicked event, in IBAction function I have tried this;

```
    // Where MyTableView is a class which loads this custom cell
    // ModalView is a name of XIB File
    MyTableView *vc = [[MyTableView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModalView" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

but it throughs error at "self.navigationController", says Property navigationController not found on object of type MyTableViewCell class, i know this is happening due to the UITableViewCell class and the self in this line is referring to the UIViewController Object and I should use awakeFromNib or something like that, but I couldn't find any sufficient example to let me achieve what I need.

Comment: tred this as well; NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ModalView" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *nView = [nib objectAtIndex:0]; but self doesn't support navigationcontroller or pushview etc, dont know how to embed view on top as a Modal View???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I have solved my problem;

In cellForRowAtIndexPath function, where I was fetching the XIB file (UITableViewCell) to represent a custom designed cell, I created a button and assign it the button from the XIB view and then attached the IBAction to it;

```
    // SimpleTableCell is the XIB filename (UITableViewCell)
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];


    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    btn = cell.btn;
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(smsBtnClicked:) 
                            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: and off course in this IBAction event 
    UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModalViewController" bundle:nil];
    [viewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:NULL];